# Merge Rows based on primary key time in dataiku

Tags: dataframe, datatable, etl, data-analysis, dataiku

I am trying to rearrange a data in dataiku platform. i am performing several operations, pivoting transposed the data but created more null data. as below

THE data i have

[image]

The Data i need it to be

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to Spark on your platform? What tools are available to you on dataiku?

Comment: If you can run SQL against it then just just do SELECT MAX(tag1), MAX(tag2), ... from TABLE group by TIME

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old but you could simply use a group visual recipe on this dataset. you would group by time and for example make the sum of your 'tags'.
you could also use some code but in this instance it's a very simpe operation in dataiku.